# Starting a process in the current command window in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, process, console

I have this in a VB.NET console application:

```
Dim p As ProcessStartInfo
p = New ProcessStartInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\bin\javac.exe",ClassName & ".java")
Dim ps As Process = Process.Start(p)
```

This does run the java compiler on the file, but it does so *in a new window*.  I want the output from javac to appear in the same console that is running my application.
How can I do this?  Perhaps there is another method for running commands in the current console?  Or maybe I can supress the second console window from opening and redirect its output to the current console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can run in the same console but you can get the output by redirecting the standard out:

```
Dim si = New ProcessStartInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\bin\javac.exe",ClassName & ".java")

si.RedirectStandardOutput = True
si.UseShellExecute = False
Dim proc = New Process() 
proc.StartInfo = si
proc.Start()
proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
proc.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Tried this and it works exactly as desired. +1 for now, and I'll probably accept this answer later. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can run in same console, because it is occupied by your application. If it is just about showing output you can use [stream redirection](http://blog.crankybit.com/redirecting-output-to-a-file-in-windows-batch-scripts/). If you do `javac [here go params] >out.txt 2>err.txt` you can later load outputs from them when `javac` finished.

You can even redirect streams to your application by [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) and [Process.StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)

Comment: +1 for the file idea, but it doesn't look like Process.StandardOutput can be used to set a different output stream; it's a readonly property.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now.  I thought you were saying to set StandardOutput to Console.OpenStandardOutput or something like that. =P

Comment: @Exp HP no, but you can read it line by line using `ReadLine` and then output using `Console.WriteLine`